# Кодирование информации

Tags: c++, файлы, кодировка

Здравствуйте! Пишу свой архиватор (C++), использую алгоритм Хаффмана. 
Не очень понял, как записать биты в бинарный файл (пишутся только байты). 
Пример: 'с' кодируется такой последовательностью битов: 1011. 
По идее, такой символ занимает меньше байта, но записать я его могу только как 4 байта. 
Единственный выход, что нашел в интернете, это упаковка битов в байт и запись этого байта в файл. Это  единственное решение или есть другие?

Comment: Записать 4 бита в файл не получится, только байт. А уж чем "добивать" оставшиеся биты - отдельный момент.

Comment: Да, записать можно минимум 1 байт. Вообще приходит в голову в самом начале указывать, какой следующий символ, примерно как это сделано в utf-8. То есть надо определиться, какие вообще последовательности у вас могут быть (4 бита, 5, 6 ...), как-то их, возможно, объединять для экономии места ну и придумать индикаторы того, как расшифровать следующие n байт. Посмотрите идею utf-8, довольно интересное  и понятное решение применили.

Comment: Что за странные идеи, напрочь хоронящие процесс сжатия информации в принципе? Обычный битовый поток давным-давно для этого придуман.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> символ занимает меньше байта, но записать я его могу только как 4 байта

С чего бы? Если символ занимает один байт, то и пишется он как один байт, а не как 4. Вы же не предполагаетте, что двоичное значение `1011` будет записано как последовательность байтов 1, 0, 1 и 1?

Что же касается записи результатов кодирования, то вам не нужно записывать каждый закодированый символ отдельно. Вам нужно накапливать результаты кодирования в буфере битов и писать его полностью. Либо фрагментами, но в любом случае эти фрагменты будут кратны байту.

А ещё лучше будет, если вы возьмёте исходники любого архиватора, в котором реализованы нужные вам алгоритмы, и, прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы, посмотрите как эти проблемы решаются другими.